# Detect FlexClient disconnect on Longpolling Channel

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, long-polling

I'm developing a chat system and i need to detect the FlexClient disconnect in Java, using the longpolling channel.

I can't use the Streaming channel, because of some bugs that this kind of channel still has. Do you have any suggestion on how could i accomplish this? I'm using BlazeDS.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect a client disconnect in real time unless using an RMTP channel which is using behind a socket. When using different channels you can do some workarounds like having some javascript in your web detecting the page unload event, or you can have your client using some kind of heart bit mechanism.